# How to build an android NDK plugin for unity that is both 32 and 64bit

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, plugins, android-ndk

I have a native Android plugin that I use in Unity3d, there is now a need to create a 64bit android package. I wish to include both 32 bit and 64 bit in the same package.

I have modified the Application.mk to build 4 plugins
Application.mk looks like this:

```
APP_OPTIM        := release
APP_ABI          := armeabi-v7a arm64-v8a x86 x86_64
APP_PLATFORM     := android-8
APP_BUILD_SCRIPT := Android.mk
```

my build plugin.sh looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo ""
echo "Compiling NativeCode.c..."
ANDROID_NDK_ROOT="/myapps/Android/android-ndk-r13b"
$ANDROID_NDK_ROOT/ndk-build NDK_PROJECT_PATH=.             NDK_APPLICATION_MK=Application.mk $*
mv libs/armeabi-v7a/libnative.so ../libnative1.so
mv libs/arm64-v8a/libnative.so ../libnative2.so
mv libs/x86/libnative.so ../libnative3.so
mv libs/x86_64/libnative.so ../libnative4.so

echo ""
echo "Cleaning up / removing build folders..."  #optional..
rm -rf libs
rm -rf obj

echo ""
echo "Done!"
```

My plugin code NativeCode.c is very simple and looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <android/log.h>
#include <string.h>


void QDebug(const char *str)
{
    __android_log_write(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "QED", str);
}
```

When I run the .sh file it creates 4 zlibnative.so files presumably one for each target platform. My question is how do I include all 4 in Unity3d plugins directory so that the Unity package uses the correct version.

The error I am getting is:

DllNotFoundException: native
06-07 18:13:07.617 29585 29608 E Unity   :   at (wrapper managed-to-native) D:QDebug (string)
06-07 18:13:07.617 29585 29608 E Unity   :   at D.logx (System.String format, System.Object[] paramList) [0x00000] in :0 
06-07 18:13:07.617 29585 29608 E Unity   :   at Sounds.Awake () [0x00000] in :0

When I build for only 32 bit and have only one Libnative.so in the plugins directory it all works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Check your script that defines the QDebug function for C#.

It has a DllImport directive that lists the name of the plugin where the function is defined.  In your case, it probably shows [DllImport(native)] or [DllImport(native1)].

Your 4 libraries should each have the same file name, but be in separate directories under your Unity Assets directory.  Then you can check the metadata for each of them from within Unity to make sure they are identified to only load for Android with the correct architecture.